# Generando un shared library de un proyecto en c++ con OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Tengo un código en C++ en visual estudio en el cual utilizo OpenCV para realizar ciertas funciones. Hasta ahora he tenido que generar un DLL para integrarlo en Unity, pero ahora tengo que crear un .so para integrarlo en Unity para después crear una aplicación de Android. La verdad es que no encuentro la manera de como hacerlo.

Y otra pregunta, tengo compilado el código fuente de OpenCV con CMake en librerías DLL, ¿como lo hago para generar los .so?

Comment: Para embeber una librería estática en Unity vas a tener que compilar posteriormente Unity... ¿seguro que eso lo que pretendes? Por otro lado deberías revisar el tema de las licencias... muchos proyectos OpenSource no te permiten integrarlos en el ejecutable final

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, la cuestion es que hata ahora he generado un codigo utilizando codigo nativo de c++ generando un DLL, lo integro en Unity y me funciona.

Ahora tnego que usar esa misma aplicacion compilando en Unity para generar una aplicacion en android. la cosa es que al tener DLL no me funciona. tengo que generar .so para que me funcione. Por ello necesito compilar mi programa en VS en un .so e integrarlo en Unity.

Comment: Una DLL es un binario externo e independiente que una aplicación puede elegir si usar o no... una librería estática es un subproducto de la compilación (el *linker* aun no la ha procesado). Para ser completamente funcional debe integrarse en un ejecutable o en una DLL

Comment: Y, por supuesto, para integrarse en un ejecutable debe compilarse dicho ejecutable. En ese momento el código de la librería estática pasa a formar parte (hablando literalmente) del ejecutable

Comment: hay que tener en cuenta que android funciona con librerias compartidas (shared library) por ello es necesario que genere esa slibrerias. mi duda es como ago para compilar mi proyecto que esta en visual estudio en .so

Comment: Una `.so` es el formato de librería compartida de Linux. Lo cual tiene sentido, puesto que Android tiene una base Linux. Asi que te va a tocar buscar un compilador/enlazador que genere para Linux con la arquitectura de CPU que tengas prevista usar. Creo que la pregunta es mas de Android que de C++

Comment: Vale, a ver. Esta pregunta está mal redactada. `.so` son las DLLs de Linux. Tal y como está escrita tu pregunta parece que lo que pretendes es pasar de librería dinámica a librería estática (de ahí esa referencia en mis primeros comentarios). Lo que tu necesitas es, como te ha comentado @Trauma, usar un compilador Linux y tirar de compilación cruzada (compilar binarios linux en entorno Windows)... el SDK de android creo que tiene herramientas para ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema de compilación. Si creas un proyecto ad-hoc sobre Visual Studio, este lo que hará es generar librerías y ejecutables con el compilador de VS en sus formatos de salida (Librería estática: .lib, Librería dinámica: .dll, Ejecutable: .exe)

Android es un sistema operativo derivado de GNU/Linux, los formatos son distintos, así que el compilador genera distintos ficheros de salida (Librería estática: .a, Librería dinámica: .so, Ejecutable: .bin). Nota: Los ficheros no necesitan tener . para funcionar como si es necesario en Windows.

Como bien apuntas en tu segunda pregunta, lo que necesitas es usar CMake para generar estos ficheros. Como estás en un ordenador con Windows, y tu librería tiene un target distinto (en este caso Android), necesitas usar un TOOLCHAIN para poder compilar los ficheros fuentes con la salida en el formato deseado. Viene perfectamente documentado en la [referencia de CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). Hay un toolchain de Android en la red mantenido por OpenCV [aquí](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake).

Si usas CMake cargando el toolchain, y has escrito el código fuente con librerías standard, debería directamente generarte los ficheros que necesitas. Si el compilador te da algún error, entonces tendrás que dar soporte con la fuente a ambos compiladores.